# browserify :- Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function

Tags: javascript, nlp, browserify

i am trying to use natural .js in my code , to use it on the client side i used browserify ,but it is giving an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function
at loadDictionary (main.js:10999)
at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:10894)
at Object.69../base_stemmer_id (main.js:11175)
at o (main.js:1)
at main.js:1
at Object.44../analyzers/sentence_analyzer (main.js:6380)
at o (main.js:1)
at main.js:1
at Object.1.natural (main.js:23)
at o (main.js:1)
```

the code is tried is

```
var natural =require("natural");
var tokenizer =new natural.WordTokenizer();
console.log(tokenizer.tokenize("my name is akash"));
```

any help?

Answer (score 0):

From the [npm page for natural.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/natural):

> "Natural" is a general natural language facility **for nodejs**.

Since this is built for Node.js, it likely uses **Node specific modules**, like `fs`, which allows Node to access the file system. The `fs` module does not exist in the front end.

So when natural.js tries to require `fs` (using Browserify, I guess), it doesn't get the actual module that Node has, thus it can't call the readFileSync method.

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to access the file system library `fs`, which is not available from a browser. Unfortunately, Browserify only converts node.js-style module imports (like `require('package-name');`) into a form the browser understands. It doesn't make all node.js packages work in the browser.

From [browserify.org](http://browserify.org/)

> Browsers don't have the `require` method defined, but Node.js does. With Browserify you can write code that uses `require` in the same way that you would use it in Node.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to browserify a library for NLP based on Natural. Finally my solution was to don't use Natural and move the stemmers/tokenizers. Right now I have the NLP library bundle working in the browser, you can find it here: https://github.com/axa-group/nlp.js/tree/master/dist
To use it better read the docs.