# Loading local JSON file asynchronously in JS

Tags: javascript, json

this is my first question here on stack overflow & I am new to coding, so I hope followed all the guidelines.

I need to find a way to load a **local** **JSON** data file **asynchronously** in JS and HTML. Then it needs to run as a webpage with a frontend on the server (displaying the data from the local JSON file to the user on the interface).
Packages or libraries like Node.js or browserify are allowed but React.js is not.

So far I am working with the live-server npm package (which is not a must) and Node.js. I tried the following approaches:

- Importing the file / JSON data is not an option since the JSON data has to be loaded asynchronously.
- require() from Node.js, which does not work, because Node.js is server-side and therefore the browser (chrome) does not have access to the require() function.
- Therefore I tried the browserify package, which lets you use require() on the browser, but I ran into the same issue as this user: [browserify :- Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52634052/browserify-uncaught-typeerror-fs-readfilesync-is-not-a-function). But browserify does not convert fs. That's the code I had:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

let jsonData;

fs.readFile('file.json', 'utf8', (error, data) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log('An error occured while trying to read file.json:', error);
    return;
  }
  jsonData = data;
  console.log('Parsed JSON data from data.json:', JSON.parse(data));
});
```

- I also tried to work with fetch(), but my understanding is that fetch() only works for URLs and not local files.

I have tried to solve this issue for many, many hours, but couldn't figure out how to do it.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: https://gomakethings.com/how-to-upload-and-process-a-json-file-with-vanilla-js/

Comment: If I am not mistaken this article is about a user uploading a JSON file. I have a local file. But the way I see it, I could use the part with // Create a new FileReader() object
 let reader = new FileReader();

 // Read the file
 reader.readAsText(file.files[0]);
The page contiunes with "This API is asynchronous, so we need to attach an onload event handler to the reader object. "
But I am forbidden from using an onload event, so I can scrap that approach.

Comment: In the question, you say that you can't use require because it does not work in the browser and you cannot use fetch because it operates on a URL and not a local file. Taken together, these two statements mean to me that the user is choosing a file from their own local computer. That is exactly the article I linked. If by the word local, you meant local on the server, then you should be able to use fetch in the browser to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use promises and do something like

```
import * as fs from 'fs';

fs.promises.readFile('file.json')
  .then((json: any) => {
    const jsonOjb: any = JSON.parse(json.toString());
  }).catch(() => {});
```

Comment: I tried that and got the following error message in the console of the browser:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "fs". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
If I write 
import * as fs from './fs'; instead 
I get the error message
GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/fs net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)